# Upload data from Linux in C++ to Firebase service

Tags: c++, linux, firebase

I'm working on an IoT application on top of embedded Linux, and I want to collect log data (mostly text files) of the devices.

The language I use is C++. I went through the documentation/tutorials of Firebase, however, it looks like only iOS, Android and Web (JS) are best supported, even the C++ part is assuming the carrier device is iOS/Android.

Is it's a good choice to use Firebase for my requirement? Should I just go ahead with C++ SDK or use REST API instead (that I can do with libcurl)

Thanks.

Comment: definitely supports desktop: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk#prerequisites-for-desktop

Comment: depending on the complexity of what you want to do, you might just want to use the REST API though. Your biggest hurdle there is likely going to be the authentication part, but if you get that out of the way then using the API is extremely simple. Since you're talking about embedded Linux, your resources might be limited which ofr me personally would be a reason to go use the REST API approach. It comes down to ease of use (SDK), or lightweight (REST API). That's my 2 cts anyway...

Comment: Sounds like an answer @EdoAkse 

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of what you want to do, you might just want to use the REST API.

Your biggest hurdle there is likely going to be the authentication part, once you get that out of the way, using the API itself is extremely simple.

Since you're talking about embedded Linux, your resources might be limited, which for me personally would be a reason to go use the REST API approach.

It comes down to ease of use (SDK), or lightweight (REST API). That's my 2 cts anyway...